# Google App Purchase option, eliminate Adds

Tags: android, android-studio, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I am done developing an app. I added the ads banner and tested it, works great. The only thing I want to do is to have the customer buy the app, and when the customer buys the app it eliminates the adds. Also I would like to ass a button so the customer presses the button to buy the app, and once the customer buys the app that button also is eliminated. First app I have developed as I am still a newbie with android studio.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to store whether the user has completed any purchases and upon loading, just don't show the ads if the user completed purchases.  You would probably also have to add in a check to see if the user processed a refund.

An alternative would be to create a separate app with no ads whatsoever and put this up for purchase on the app store.

Comment: Ok, but what I am trying to do is once the user purchases the app it removed the purchase button/icon and ads. So what would be the best was to go about this? Just copy the activities and the bought version remove the ads and purchase button so when the user buys it it uploads that version instead? Would you happen to have an example or know of any documentation?